# How to find conditional probability P(X<x|Y=y) using copulas?

Tags: r, copula

I am trying to find conditional probability of the form `P(X<x|Y=y)` for two jointly distributed random variables based on the copula estimate from training data. I use R package `copula` but can not figure out the best way to do it.

What I do now - estimate empirical copula parameters on training data, generate 100000 outcomes from this distribution, construct rank-transformed data for testing data based on training data, find number of cases `X<x` within `Y=y+/-eps` for each outcome in testing data based on generated distribution. The code for doing thing is below.

Could you please advice whether there is better way of finding `P(X<x|Y=y)` for testing data based on the training data?

```
    require(copula)

    t.cop0 <- tCopula(0.5,dim=2,dispstr='un',df=1.7)
    gendata <- rCopula(300,t.cop0)
    train <- gendata[1:199,]
    test <- gendata[200:300,]

    ptrain <- pobs(train)
    tau <- cor(train,method='kendall')[2]
    t.cop <- tCopula(tau,dim=2,dispstr='un',df=3)
    fit.mpl <- fitCopula(t.cop,ptrain,method='mpl',estimate.variance=FALSE)
    empiricalCopula <- tCopula(fit.mpl@estimate[1],dim=2,dispstr='un',df=fit.mpl@estimate[2])

    p1 <- sapply(as.numeric(test[,1]),function(q)rank(c(q,train[,1]))[1]/nrow(train+2))
    p2 <- sapply(as.numeric(test[,2]),function(q)rank(c(q,train[,2]))[1]/nrow(train+2))
    ptest <- cbind(p1,p2)

    e <- rCopula(100000,empiricalCopula)
    eps <- .1
    cp <- sapply(1:nrow(ptest),function(i)
            sum(e[,2]<=ptest[i,2] & e[,1]>=(ptest[i,1]-eps) & e[,1]<=(ptest[i,1]+eps))/
            sum(e[,1]>=(ptest[i,1]-eps) & e[,1]<=(ptest[i,1])+eps))
    cp
```

Comment: And how to find, for example $P(X>a|Y>b)$ in terms of `spcopula` package, without calculating double integrals of copula density?

Comment: the df=1.7 was used in the second line. The df is the degree of freedom It must be integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a bivariate copula $C(u,v)$, a bivariate CDF $H(x,y)$ and marginal CDFs $F(x)$ and $G(y)$ with $H(x,y)=C(F(x),G(y))$. Then, what you are targeting at is (with some abuse of notation):

$$P(X < x | Y=y) = \frac{P(X < x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial v} C(F(x), G(y)) \cdot g(y)}{g(y)} = \frac{\partial}{\partial v} C(F(x), G(y))$$

The partial derivatives of copulas are available from the [spcopula](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/spcopula/) package on r-forge. Your R call for $P(X < 0.2 | Y=0.3)$ assuming for instance a Gumbel copula with parameter 5 and standard normal margins would then look like:

```
library(spcopula)
ddvCopula(c(pnorm(0.2), pnorm(0.3)), gumbelCopula(5))
[1] 0.3834244
```

Comment: Do you mean $P(X \leq x | Y=y)$?

Comment: @KiranK., how to simplify if the conditional probability is  P(X<x|Y<y)? Would it be the same?

Answer (score 0):

in R package VineCopula:

```
library(VineCopula)
# for Gumbel copula with parameter =5
A = BiCop(family=4, par=5, tau = NULL, check.pars = TRUE)
u1 = 0.03
u2 = 0.3
B = BiCopHfunc1(u1, u2, A)
```

Comment: How to proceed if I need to calculate P(X<x|Y<y) instead of P(X<x|Y=y)?